# Why does compiled Regex check Culture so many times?

Tags: .net, regex, performance, culture

Whilst profiling some code that uses a compiled regular expression, I noticed that the .NET RegexRunner makes an awful lot of calls finding the CurrentCulture. In fact it does it two different ways - GetCurrentCultureNoAppX and get_CurrentCulture.

As this profiling screenshot shows, it checks 3.2billion times and that is 25% of the total time taken:-

[image: Original Profiling results]

I tried adding the RegexOptions.CultureInvariant option and that reduced the number of calls down to 4.8million or so and 5% which is better:-

[image]

But my question is:-

Why does it get the culture so many times and not just the once at the start of performing the scan?
(Surely there is no use-case for dealing with a change of culture mid-scan)

As requested in comments and just in case it helps, here is the Regex - basically just grabbing some data from a web page into Named Groups.

```
@"(?><td\s*class=""XXX"">\s*(?<X1>[^<]+?)\s*</td>)(?>\s*<td[^>]+>\s*(?<X2>[^<]+?)\s*</td>)(?>\s*<td[^>]+>\s*(?<X3>[^<]+?)\s*</td>)(?>\s*<td[^>]+>\s*(?>(?<X4>[^<]+?)\s*</td>))(?>\s*<td[^>]+>\s*(?<X5>[^<]+?)\s*</td>)?(?>\s*<td[^>]+>\s*(?<X7>[^<]+?)\s*</td>)(?>\s*<td[^>]+>\s*(?<X8>[^<]+?)\s*</td>)(?>\s*<td[^>]+>\s*(?<X9>[^<]+?)\s*</td>)(?>\s*<td[^>]+>\s*(?<X10>[^<]+?)\s*</td>)(?>\s*<td[^>]+>\s*(?<X11>[^<]+?)\s*</td>)\s*</tr>"
```

and the options used were:

```
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
```

Comment: I've got to ask... Is there anything unusual in your regex?

Comment: if you show your regex it will help others lot more to diagnose your problem. 3.2 billion calls does not help to get your answer

Comment: It looks like its related to converting to lowercase.  The culture contains the rules for doing that.  We could help you more if you actually showed us the regex.

Comment: I don't think the Regex is really relevant - the question is about why RegexRunner is not getting the Culture just the once - but I'll post it anyway (beware, I am not an expert at this and just hack away until I get the right results so don't laugh if there is a better way!)

Comment: You should include more code context